# matching first character on MS dos

Tags: batch-file, match

i have a problem here,

i want to write and match a character in file then exec some command, but i have this wrong,..! you can try these command..

```
c:>\echo 1 >file.txt
c:>\set /p var=<file.txt
c:>\if %var% EQU "1" (echo 21 ) ELSE (echo 10)
```

you will get the value is `10`, i try another way to write the variable to file.

```
c:>\set /p=1 <nul>file.txt
c:>\set /p var=<file.txt
c:>\if %var% EQU "1" (echo 21 ) ELSE (echo 10)
```

if you want to view the data on the `file.txt` and `var` :

```
c:>\type file.txt
1
c:>\echo %var%
1
c:>\if %var% EQU "1" (echo 21 ) ELSE (echo 10)
10
```

thank for helping.

Comment: I highly doubt you are using MS DOS... What OS are you really using? The command prompt in XP and newer is very different then MS DOS. Also your OS may matter if you are on NT 6+ for some commands. Also, what is your question exactly? What are you trying to match?

Comment: Your %var% is not "1", it's "1 ". Verify with echo -%var%-

Comment: The problem is the "if" sintax, the right is :
_if %var% EQU 1 (echo 21 ) ELSE (echo 10)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `set /a` command you can remove unwanted invisible spaces from numeric variables. Try this:

```
C:\>echo 1 >file.txt

C:\>set /p var=<file.txt

C:\>set /a var=%var%
1
C:\>if "%var%" EQU "1" (echo 21 ) ELSE (echo 10)
21
```

Answer (score 1):

As Stephan suggested, you are echoing `1*space*` out to `file.txt`.  Try putting your redirection at the beginning of the line, like this:

```
>file.txt echo 1
```

You could also enclose your echo command in parentheses, like this:

```
(echo 1)>file.txt
```

I think `>file.txt echo 1` is more readable than `(echo 1)>file.txt`, but your mileage may vary.

Unfortunately, you can't solve the problem by simply removing the space after `1`, as cmd will interpret it as `echo stdout>file.txt`, and `file.txt` would have the contents `ECHO is on.`

Answer (score 0):

Beware trailing spaces on lines, **BUT** `ECHO 1>file.txt` will direct the output of STDOUT to the file because you have a digit directly before the redirector.

```
ECHO 1 >file.txt
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (file.txt) DO ECHO +%%i+
(ECHO 2) >file.txt
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (file.txt) DO ECHO +%%i+
>file.txt ECHO 3
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (file.txt) DO ECHO +%%i+
>file.txt (ECHO 4)
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (file.txt) DO ECHO +%%i+
```

Next point is that `1` is the content of `var` and this is **NOT** equal to `"1"`

Environment variables are always strings.

correct this to `if "%var%" equ "1" (echo 21 ) ELSE (echo 10)`